# Lein test failing on unbound var when using declare

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Why is the last assertion from the following test failing when run by using `lein test`?

I don't understand why the first two assertions get the late bound value properly, but the `fromvar` value is seen as unbound.

```
(declare x)

(def fromvar x)
(defn fromfun [] x)

(deftest declaretest

  ;; These pass fine
  (is (= 1 x))
  (is (= 1 (fromfun)))

  ;; This fails on lein test:
  ;; expected: (= 1 fromvar)
  ;;   actual: (not (= 1 #<Unbound Unbound: #'my-test/value>))
  (is (= 1 fromvar)))

(def x 1)
```

Comment: using `value` as your value makes it difficult to use proper terminology clearly in answering your question

Comment: Sure, you're right, changed it to x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`def` doesn't ensure that `fromvar` is tied to the binding of `value`. It assigns to `fromvar` the value of `x` at the time `def` was called. Since `x` is not defined yet, the value is unbound (literally an instance of the inner class `Var.Unbound`). `fromfun` does not inline the value of `x` when compiled, so it is free to find the correct value at runtime, reflecting the later assignment.

Comment: Allright, so this is not anything esoteric at all, I was confused of this because using IntelliJ and reloading files led to a situation where the test in question starts to pass. But that has to be because (declare x) for already bound x does nothing, so the x actually has a value next time. Thanks for clearing this out.